# Proof of Lindelöf Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, alternative-proof

I have been surfing the net to read the proof of the Lindelöf Theorem:

> Let $U\in \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and $U=\bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda}
>  U_{\lambda}$where $\Lambda$ is an index set, $\{U_{\lambda}\}$ is a
>   collection of open sets. Then, ther eis a countable subcollection
>   $\{U_i\}$ of $\{U_{\lambda}\}$ so that $U=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty U_i$.

I found out that most of the proof in the internet are from complex analysis. The level does not fit me as a beginner of real analysis, so I hereby ask for a more **detailed and suitable proof**. (Again, please don't lead me to some websites which talk about complex analysis!)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The point here is that subspaces of Euclidean space are still separable. From this dense countable subset, choose an open set from your cover which contains one of those elements. You'll make at most countably many choices which still cover your set.

Comment: @Bryan this does not work. Use a countable base instead.

Comment: I think those complex analysis proofs you found pertain to a **different Lindelöf theorem**. The same Lindelöf (I guess), but he had more than one theorem.

Comment: Repeating what bof said: the Lindelof theorem in complex analysis (which has proofs involving complex analysis) is not the same theorem as the Lindelof theorem quoted by the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Check that the collection $\mathcal{B}$ of open balls $B(x, r)$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $x$ ranges over the points with all rational coordinates (of which there are only countably many) and $r>0$ ranges over the rational numbers, is a countable base of $\mathbb{R}^n$, which means that every open set $O$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be written as a union of members from $\mathcal{B}$. Enumerate  $\mathbb{B}$ as $\{B_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

For every $x \in U$, pick $\lambda(x) \in \Lambda$ such that $x \in U_{\lambda(x)}$. Then pick $n(x) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x \in B_{n(x)} \subseteq U_{\lambda(x)}$. For every $n$ in $I = \{n_x: x \in U \}$ (which is countable) pick one $\lambda(n)$ such that $\lambda(n) = \lambda(n_x)$ where $n_x = n$. Then $\{ U_{\lambda(n)} : n \in I \}$ is the required countable subfamily: pick $p \in U$, then we have $n(p)$ and $\lambda(p)$ such that $p \in B_{n(p)} \subseteq U_{\lambda(p)}$, so $n = n(p) \in I$, and we have $\lambda(n)$ to witness that $p \in U_{\lambda(n)}$, as required.

This could all be made explicit if we start with a concrete enumeration of the base, and take minimal index elements whenever we make choices above. The above is just a general proof of the fact that a second countable space is hereditarily Lindelöf...

Comment: Fully agreed, only the (Axiom of) Choice requirements are not clear to me. I understand to choose $n(x)$ from a countable set (the indicated countable base $\mathcal{B}$ of the second countable space $\mathbb{R}^n$), but how to choose $\lambda(x)$ and $\lambda(n)$ in $\Lambda$ explicitly? $\Lambda$ is not assumed countable.

Comment: @MatthiasHübner I think the result in general will require countable choice. This is also needed to show that a countable union of countable sets is countable so considered uncontroversial.

Comment: thank you very much. I read the Lindelöf Lemma proof first more than 30 years ago in Kelley's Topology on page 49; in these ancient times it was not (yet) so popular to underline the precise Choice requirements for every statement. I have been wondering about this at least 10 years, but only today finally dared to ask here. So many thanks for your comment.

Comment: @MatthiasHübner I think it still isn’t popular, but at least these questions have been studied more (more forcing techniques, reverse mathematics etc.) Most topologists don’t care and just assume AC all the time. Quoting Mary-Ellen “we start by well-ordering everything in sight”..

Answer (score -3):

Choose one open set $U_\lambda$ for every $n$-tuple with all rational coordinates.

Comment: This need not be enough, in general. This would imply that a separable space would be hederitarily Lindelöf...